# Bind CheckBox from DataTemplate to TemplatedParent in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have next code:

```
  <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0,1,0" MinHeight="80" Name="lbThemes" SelectionMode="Multiple" IsEnabled="True">                         
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox x:Name="ThemeCheckbox" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=label, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to bind my checkbox in dataTemplate to the ListBoxItem IsSelected property. Any idea how can I do this?
P.S. I have use Multiple Selesction mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ThemeCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" />
```